# Use of "depend on" and "depending on"

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs, gerunds

1. The family name may appear on the left side or the right side of the door, **depends on** which floor you are on.
2. A careful driver watches the road and goes slowly or quickly **depending upon** the condition of the road.

In 1 sentence it uses **depends** while in 2 **depending**. why? Is there any rule regarding uses of  **depending on or depend on**?

Comment: The first sentence isn't syntactically valid. You could fix it by inserting *"**, which**"* after ***name*** (making a comma-delimited non-restrictive relative clause). Or by inserting ***it*** after the existing comma (which would then be better as a full stop, semicolon, or dash, since what follows is then an independent clause with its own subject and predicate.

Answer (score 6):

**Some new examples**

> 1. His success in the interview depends on the interviewer.
> 2. He could do well in the interview, depending on the interviewer.

To understand the difference between *depends* in sentence (1) and *depending on* in sentence (2), we need to understand the grammar of the sentences.

In sentence (1) *depends* is a verb. It is the main verb in the sentence. The subject of *depends* is the noun phrase, *his success in the interview*.

In sentence (2) the main clause in the sentence is:

- He could do well in the interview

The main verb phrase in that clause is *could do*. The subject is *he*. The part at the end of sentence (2), *depending on the interviewer*, gives us extra information. It is not essential for the grammar, or for the meaning. This means that it is an *adjunct*. It is extra.

In sentence (2) *depending on the interviewer* is a preposition phrase. In this sentence *depending* looks like a verb - but it is not! It is a preposition. This preposition takes another preposition *on* as a complement. In example (2), the complement of *on* is *the interviewer*. This gives us one big preposition phrase:

- depending on the interviewer.

**The Original Poster's question**

We use *depending on* to add on extra information to a sentence or clause. We use the verb *depend* when we need to use a verb.

The Original Poster's examples both need the preposition construction *depending on/upon*. This is because they are adding extra information to a full clause. I have put the main clause in brackets, [ ], below:

1. [ The family name may appear on the left side or the right side of the door ] ***depending on which floor you are on***.
2. [ A careful driver watches the road and goes slowly or quickly ] ***depending upon the condition of the road***.

The ***part in bold*** tells us what the situation in the main clause depends on. We can divide the sentences into two parts, so that we have two sentences for each example:

3. [The family name may appear on the left side or the right side of the door ]. ***This depends  on which floor you are on***.
4. [ A careful driver watches the road and goes slowly or quickly ]. ***This will depend upon the condition of the road***.

In the examples above, the word *this* refers to the situation which we described in the first sentence. The word *this* is the subject of the second sentences. So this time we use the verb *depend* not the preposition *depending*.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Not to disagree (because I do agree with your answer), but I'm not sure if it's safe enough to call *depending* a preposition. I believe that CGEL (which I don't have) analyzes this kind of phrase as a PP (prepositional phrase, not very sure about the *-al* part, though), but maybe they avoid calling *depending* a preposition right out.

Comment: @damkerng, Alas I don't have it with me either. But I think I remember it correctly. I *believe* they class it as a prep, but am not sure. Will check when I get back:) Thanks!

Comment: Nice post. :) -- But perhaps you could demonstrate that it is a PP by easily moving it about in the sentence, which would show it not linking to a subject (which that phrase would need if it were a VP), via an edit in your post?

Comment: Oh, just wanted to make sure, that my last example sometimes doesn't need a comma, e.g. "Tom sat in a chair reading a book", or "Tom sat quietly in a corner reading a book".

Comment: @F.E. I went a bit further than I'd have liked in being too technical in this post - and not far enough at the same time ... How about asking a more specific question?

Comment: @F.E. ... and maybe someone else will answer it :) Might use the X-mas break to do a few of those posts that really, really are very overdue ;)

Comment: @DamkerngT. It seems that H&P don't actually discuss *depending*. However, they do discuss similar prepositions such as *according* in the prepositional construction *according to* as well as the prepositions *owing* and *pertaining* which both also take prepositional complements headed by *to*. The preposition *depending* also seems to be very similar to the prepositions *barring, excluding,  failing, providing, given, regarding, following* and so forth. Cf pp. 564, 610-611 if you get a chance to look at a copy of CaGEL. :)

Comment: @Araucaria Thank you very much for the info. If only I had a copy of CGEL... :-)

Comment: Do you need to put a comma before depending？It seems better to understand if there is.

Answer (score 2):

If the sentence is continued, I'd go for *depending*. If you want to use the simple tense, it looks more natural when used to *re-introduce* what it 'depends' on.

Compare:

> The family name may appear on the left side or the right side of the door, *depending* on which floor you are on.

over

> The family name may appear on the left side or the right side of the door. *It depends* which floor you are on.

Comment: The first one isn't continuous, it isn't a verb old bean!

Comment: @Araucaria I meant 'continued' (not in the context of 'tenses').